# How to convert models between Network Service and Room Entities

Tags: android, list, kotlin, android-room, data-class

I'm learning Kotlin making different exercises, and I have a doubt converting models using Room. I have a model from the network service, and another model from Room entities. One of them has a list of results, and I don't know how to convert in the proper way.

**Room Entities**

```
@Entity
class DatabaseRoot(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "id") val id: Int = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "page")val page : Int,
    @Embedded @ColumnInfo(name = "results") val results : List<DatabaseResults>,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "total_pages")val total_pages : Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "total_results")val total_results : Int
)

class DatabaseResults (
    @ColumnInfo(name = "adult") val adult : Boolean,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "backdrop_path") val backdrop_path : String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "genre_ids") val genre_ids : List<Int>,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id") val id : Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "original_language") val original_language : String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "original_title") val original_title : String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "overview") val overview : String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "popularity") val popularity : Double,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "poster_path") val poster_path : String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "release_date") val release_date : String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title") val title : String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "video") val video : Boolean,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "vote_average") val vote_average : Double,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "vote_count") val vote_count : Int
)

class DatabaseResultsTypeConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    fun listToJson(value: List<DatabaseResults>?) = Gson().toJson(value)

    @TypeConverter
    fun jsonToList(value: String) = Gson().fromJson(value, Array<DatabaseResults>::class.java).toList()

}
```

**Models from Service Network**

```
@Parcelize
data class Root (
    @SerializedName("page") val page : Int,
    @SerializedName("results") val results : List<Results>,
    @SerializedName("total_pages") val total_pages : Int,
    @SerializedName("total_results") val total_results : Int
) : Parcelable

@Parcelize

data class Results (
    @SerializedName("adult") val adult : Boolean,
    @SerializedName("backdrop_path") val backdrop_path : String,
    @SerializedName("genre_ids") val genre_ids : List<Int>,
    @SerializedName("id") val id : Int,
    @SerializedName("original_language") val original_language : String,
    @SerializedName("original_title") val original_title : String,
    @SerializedName("overview") val overview : String,
    @SerializedName("popularity") val popularity : Double,
    @SerializedName("poster_path") val poster_path : String,
    @SerializedName("release_date") val release_date : String,
    @SerializedName("title") val title : String,
    @SerializedName("video") val video : Boolean,
    @SerializedName("vote_average") val vote_average : Double,
    @SerializedName("vote_count") val vote_count : Int
) : Parcelable
```

I need to make a function to convert between models, but I don't have it clear, maybe something like this:

```
fun List<Root>.asDatabaseModel(): Array<DatabaseRoot> {
    return map {
        DatabaseRoot(
           ...
        )
    }.toTypedArray()
}

fun List<DatabaseRoot>.asDomainModel(): List<Root> {
    return map {
        Root(
            ...
        )
    }
}
```

Could someone tells me how to do this with a list inside.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a secondary constructor in both the classes that will define how they will be converted with each other like

```
class DatabaseResults (
  @ColumnInfo(name = "adult") val adult : Boolean,
  @ColumnInfo(name = "backdrop_path") val backdrop_path : String,
  @ColumnInfo(name = "genre_ids") val genre_ids : List<Int>,
  @ColumnInfo(name = "id") val id : Int,
  @ColumnInfo(name = "original_language") val original_language : String,
  @ColumnInfo(name = "original_title") val original_title : String,
  @ColumnInfo(name = "overview") val overview : String,
  @ColumnInfo(name = "popularity") val popularity : Double,
  @ColumnInfo(name = "poster_path") val poster_path : String,
  @ColumnInfo(name = "release_date") val release_date : String,
  @ColumnInfo(name = "title") val title : String,
  @ColumnInfo(name = "video") val video : Boolean,
  @ColumnInfo(name = "vote_average") val vote_average : Double,
  @ColumnInfo(name = "vote_count") val vote_count : Int
) {
  constructor(results: Results) : this(
     adult,
     backdrop_path,
     genre_ids,
     id,
     original_language,
     original_title,
     overview,
     popularity,
     poster_path,
     release_date,
     title,
     video,
     vote_average,
     vote_count
  )
}
```

And so on for all the classes

Then you can use the extension function to map list from one type to another.

Also if you are going to use the same variable names for database columns and json keys you are good without specifying the column info and serialised name. Also if your network model is going to be saved inside the database with the same fields it would be better if you directly convert the response json to your db entity and save that instead of going through the trouble of conversion.